# Using dynamic subqueries as column header

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns foo, bar and baz, where foo is repeated once for each entry in bar, with a possible entry in baz for each bar. As an example:

```
|-----|-----|-----|
| foo | bar | baz |
|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  1  |alpha|
|  1  |  2  |beta |
|  1  |  3  |gamma|
|  2  |  1  |delta|
|  2  |  2  |beta |
|  2  |  3  |kappa|
|  3  |  1  |     |
|  3  |  2  |     |
|  3  |  3  |iota |
|-----|-----|-----| etc
```

This table, in practice, has millions of entries. I'm looking for situations where two different foo entries have matching bar+baz entries (for instance, it would find foo 1 and foo 2 above, since they both have `beta` in their bar 2), for a given range of foo, it's not looking at the entire table.

I'm not sure if this is possible and various permutations of subqueries haven't worked so far, but I've been trying to make a query that lists foo, then the next columns are `baz where bar = x and foo = [the foo for the current row]`

So the table above, if looking at bar 2 and bar 3, would be:

```
|-----|-----|-----|
| foo |bar=2|bar=3|
|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |beta |gamma|
|  2  |beta |kappa|
|  3  |     |iota |
|-----|-----|-----|
```

I'm relatively inexperienced with sql, so I may not be aware of a particular syntax that does this and I haven't been able to Google any up. I've tried using

```
select foo, (baz where bar=2) as 'bar=2', (baz where bar=3) as 'bar=3' from....
```

To no good result, which wasn't entirely unexpected. I've considered putting full select queries as the column header, but can't see a way to reference 'foo for this line' in them. Am I just chasing an impossible idea here? The alternative is to use an external application to run many smaller queries and store the data that way instead, but that's my plan for if it cannot be done entirely within sql server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Are there always exacly three `bar` values per `foo`?

Comment: SQL server 2008. The number of `bar` per `foo` is consistent, although closer to 100 in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for situations where two different foo entries have matching bar+baz entries (for instance, it would find foo 1 and foo 2 above, since they both have beta in their bar 2)

That's quite simple. You can accomplish this by self-joining.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.foo != t2.foo
WHERE
t1.bar = t2.bar 
AND t1.baz = t2.baz
```

See it working live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4611/4/0).

The rest of your question I don't understand at all. It's like it has nothing to do with what you asked above. Why looking at bar = 2 and bar = 3. And why is gamma, kappa and iota listed in the result? Please clarify...

Comment: The additional data is me having a specific idea in mind, but it's non-essential, other than I'm looking for `foo` where three different `bar` values match. It hadn't occurred to me though that I can join tables to copies of themselves, that's pretty much what I needed, thanks.